# "Стряпня" — синонимы

Tags: стилистика, лексика, синонимы

Писал один текст, и там речь шла о неких кулинарных произведениях определенного человека. Каким словом их можно назвать, кроме "стряпня", подскажите, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы о результете и процессе?
Результат - еда, кушанье, блюда...
Процесс - готовка.

Answer (score 1):

Синонимы к слову СТРЯПНЯ:
• готовка 
• жаренье 
• жарня 
• кашеварство 
• кухня 
• кушанье
• стряпание 
• стряпанье 
• готовка
См.Словарь синонимов ASIS, Тришин В.Н., Малый академический словарь

Comment: Кроме "готовки" все упомянутые слова - весьма ограниченнык частичные синогимы. К тому же в одну кучу свалены три значения слова стряпня. Два указанных (прцесс и результат) и переноное.

Comment: Если к слову имеются синонимы, но не все подходят по смыслу, значит они   объеденены как  близкие по своему значению слова. А уж какое слово подойдет - решать автору и независимо от того, в "одну кучу свалены три значения слова" или нет.

Comment: Это где такой подход проповедуется?  
Нормально все-таки давать синонимы к конкретным значениям.

Comment: Наугад взяла синонимический ряд прилаг. ПОЛЕЗНЫЙ - пользительный, благодатный, благодетельный, благотворный, лечебный, целебный, целительный, живительный, животворный, выгодный, годный, пригодный, дельный, практичный, плодотворный, производительный, продуктивный, благодарный, выигрышный, добычный, доходный, прибыльный, прибыточный, спасительный.

Comment: Мы можем сказать "полезный (пользительный, лечебный, целебный, живительный) напиток". Но мы не можем употребить в своей речи синоним "добычный напиток", потому что напитков таких не бывает. Получается, что синонимический ряд существует, но не все синонимы подходят по смыслу в конкретно взятом  случае.

Comment: Рискну повторить вопрос.

*Это где такой подход проповедуется?*